# Django-allauth password reset link not open

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have successfully integrated django-allauth in my project for local user authentication.
The only problem remains is that the link a user is sent to his/her email account upon forget password case is not loaded.

My settings has  `SITE_ID = 1` and in the admin section, this site-id  is configured as `locahost:8000`.

Looking at these settings the link user received seems quite correct that is : `locahost:8000/accounts/password/reset/key/2-3ub-2debf660112bbea8682b/`

(NOTE http:// is there in the link...)

But it does not seem to open and instead, I receive `this page is not available` error.

Does resetting the password work with localhost settings? Or I am missing something else?

Comment: how does your `urls.py` look like?

Comment: Well the urls.py of the project includes **(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')), **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything with allauth works with localhost.

If you use `localhost`, do it without `http://`, or otherwise use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and it will also work.

In your case the complete links would be:

```
locahost:8000/accounts/password/reset/key/2-3ub-2debf660112bbea8682b/
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password/reset/key/2-3ub-2debf660112bbea8682b/
```

Comment: as I mentioned in my question NOTE: http:// is present in the link. I didn't add here as the editor does not permit me to do so

Comment: The link I receive in the email is perfectly OK. http://locahost:8000/accounts/password/reset/key/2-3ub-2debf660112bbea8682b/ The thing is its not being loaded

Comment: my apologyies....as you asked me to do it without http:// part for localhost. Any how the result is the same in case of localhost. But you are right it seems to work, if I user 127.0.0.1:8000 instead. So thanks for the help